# как сохранить композицию с яндекс.музыки?

Tags: unix, firefox

очень понравилась одна композиция с *яндекс.музыки*.

как её извлечь из кэша браузера *firefox* и сохранить для оффлайн-прослушивания?

Comment: Данный вопрос не относится к теме сообщества Stack Overflow на русском

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к теме сайта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. на служебной странице `about:cache` в разделе `диск` скопируйте значение параметра `storage disk location` примерно такого вида:

   ```
   /home/user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/blablabla.default/cache2
   ```

   и сохраните в какой-нибудь переменной оболочки. например, `cache`:

   ```
   $ cache=/home/user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/blablabla.default/cache2
   ```
2. запустите в *яндекс.музыке* воспроизведение нужной композиций, дождитесь пока файл полностью загрузится (заполнится линейка прогресса), а затем выполните команду (там же, где присваивали значение переменной `cache`):

   ```
   $ (cd $cache/entries/ && ls -t | head -n 100 | xargs file | grep -i mpeg | sed "s/:.*//;s,^,$cache/entries/,")
   ```

   приблизительный вывод:

   ```
   /home/user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/blablabla.default/cache2/entries/D0E0C0FC32606E2D0203102310B828477A09B1D5
   /home/user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/blablabla.default/cache2/entries/ED4648D478D231DE3EBFCDC0D0DB239FEE5200D3
   /home/user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/blablabla.default/cache2/entries/0575D4401C1287295F80B50AFE125A895805CCDF
   ```

   строк может быть несколько. самая верхняя из них, скорее всего, и будет нужным файлом. ну, может быть вторая-третья (*js* иногда подгружают загодя что-нибудь, например, рекламу). проверьте любым имеющимся аудио-плейером, например, `mplayer` (или `vlc` или ещё чем-нибудь):

   ```
   $ mplayer /путь/к/файлу
   ```
3. скопируйте файл в нужное место под нужным именем.

#### немного подкапотного:

- `ls -t` — выведет список файлов в текущем каталоге, отсортировав по времени модификации, самые новые — в начале
- `head -n 100` — первые 100 строк из списка. так много потому, что кэшируется масса «очень нужного мусора». если вышеприведённая команда ничего не вернёт, в первую очередь стоит увеличить это число
- `xargs file` — для отобранных файлов будет выполнена команда `file список файлов …`
- `grep -i mpeg` — для аудио-файлов с *яндекс.музыки* у меня программа `file` возвращает такое описание:

  ```
  MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 192 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
  ```

  вот по строчке `mpeg` их и отбираем. кстати, рекламные ролики могут быть с таким описанием (по-моему, оно иногда варьируется, в отличие от возвращаемого для музыкальных композиций):

  ```
  Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
  ```
- `sed "s/:.*//;s,^,$cache/entries/,"` — отрезаем описание, добавляемое программой *file*, в начало добавляем путь (программа *ls* не возвращает полный путь (если только не запускать с опцией `-d`, но для такого количества файлов, как в каталоге с кэшем браузера, это вызывает ошибку `Argument list too long`), потому сначала и выполняется `cd`, а вся команда заключена в скобки — чтобы выполнялась в под-оболочке, и не менялся текущий каталог)

Answer (score 2):

1. Открыть вкладку "Сеть" в инструментах разработчика (в Firefox клавишей F12)
2. Дождаться загрузки очередной композиции (или переключиться вручную)
3. Скопировать URL свежевыполненного запроса, в ответ на который пришёл музыкальный файл (лекго выяснить по колонке "Тип")
4. Открыть этот адрес в новой вкладке, а на запрос сохранения файла дать ему подходящее название (не забудьте проставить теги в этом mp3)

[image: Монитор сети в Firefox]

Comment: 1. файл-то уже в кэше. 2. вопрос-то про «извлечь из кэша». 3. и вообще: без командной строки — неспортивно.

Comment: зато даже под виндами работать будет)) без grep, file, xargs...

Comment: ну, для «измученных нарзаном», пусть, конечно, будет и такой ответ. только это ответ на совсем другой вопрос: *ms/windows* (насколько мне известно, вполне намеренно) несовместима с *unix* чуть более чем полностью (о программе под названием «совместимость с unix» я в курсе).