# как добавить/изменить id3/id3v2-метки в mp3-файле (в командной строке)?

Tags: unix, mp3

ну вот сохранил я файл: [как сохранить композицию с яндекс.музыки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/674605/178576)

а как в него добавить артиста/название и прочую информацию в виде id3-меток?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если использовать только латиницу, достаточно программы `id3` (доступна в репозиториях популярных дистрибутивов):

```
$ id3 -a "pushkin" -t "pesn o veschem olege" /путь/к/файлу.mp3
```

если же хочется использовать кириллицу (в кодировке *utf-8*), да чтоб она ещё и корректно отображалась в (не совсем кривых) аудио-плейерах, то надо добавлять метки второй версии — `id3v2` — с помощью одноимённой программы (тоже много где доступна):

```
$ id3v2 -a "пушкин" -t "песнь о вещем олеге" /путь/к/файлу.mp3
```

(вроде бы, имеет смысл при этом и удалить метки первой версии, добавив опцию `-s`/`--delete-v1`)

---

про другие метки/опции смотрите в соответствующей документации:

```
$ man id3
$ man id3v2
```